# Split columns with mixed integers an tuples to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
   a     b   
0  (0,1) 1
1  1     (1,2)
2  2     3
```

The desired output is:

```
    w  x  y  z
0   0  1  1  0
1   1  0  1  2
2   2  0  3  3
```

The problem is, that the tuples can have multiple different lenghts.
The following tolist() only works for tuples of length 2 and not for mixed columns.

```
df[['w', 'x']]=pd.DataFrame(df['a'].tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is add tuples if scalars and then create new columns:

```
def f(col):
    return pd.DataFrame([x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x, ) 
                        for x in col]).fillna(0).astype(int)

df[['w', 'x']]=df.pop('a').pipe(f)
df[['y', 'z']]=df.pop('b').pipe(f)

print (df)
   w  x  y  z
0  0  1  1  0
1  1  0  1  2
2  2  0  3  0
```

More general solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs= [pd.DataFrame([x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x, ) for x in df.pop(c)], 
                    index=df.index) for c in df.columns]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, ignore_index=True).fillna(0).astype(int)

print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  1  0
1  1  0  1  2
2  2  0  3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to `str` and then `strip` the `()` and `split` by `,`

```
>>> df[['w', 'x']] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('a')
                                    .astype(str)
                                    .str.strip('(/)')
                                    .str.split(',')
                                    .tolist()).fillna(0).astype(int)

>>> df[['y', 'z']] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('b')
                                    .astype(str)
                                    .str.strip('(/)')
                                    .str.split(',')
                                    .tolist()).fillna(0).astype(int)

>>> df

   w  x  y  z
0  0  1  1  0
1  1  0  1  2
2  2  0  3  0
```